# Fourier transform of a 2D data of position coordinates

Tags: fortran, 2d, fft

I have one file containing position coordinates (`x` and `Y`) of `N` particles in 2D. I want to do the Fourier transform of such a 2D data set (basically Fourier transform of density). I want to see whether there is any symmetry in the system. I don't know how to do the Fourier transform for such a data set. I am using Fortran 90. I tried to do the discrete Fourier transform. But how to choose the `Kx` and `Ky` (momentum vector along `X` and `Y`) values? Assume that initially I don't know the lattice structure. Can I take the length `L_x` along `X` as the (maximum - minimum) value of `X`-coordinate and similarly for `Y`?

Comment: Use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. You should definitely show some code.

Comment: Perhaps site like http://scicomp.stackexchange.com would be better. Your decision. Do not post to both, leave it here or post there and delete here.